# Java I/O Loop throttling due to UI Updates

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a copy-paste program for exercise. What I noticed is, that updating the ui in the `while` operation of the I/O, i throttle the transfer speed down to 40%. What took 4 seconds to copy now takes 8.

For example:

```
int b;
long total = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
while ((b = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
        out.write(buf, 0, b);
        ui.setSoFar(total);
        total += b;
}
```

The `ui.setSoFar()` just calls the `setText()` method on a `JLabel` inside a `JFrame`

The `out` and `in` vars are a `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.

With a Kingston SHF37A/120G throttled to SATA II speeds, copying a 313MB files takes around 8 seconds, which is about 40MB/s.

If i modify the code to look like this:

```
int b;
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
while ((b = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
        out.write(buf, 0, b);
}
```

Which is a simple loop, nothing in-between the read and write, copying a 313MB file takes around 3 seconds, which is 100MB/s.

That is almost a 60% difference in through-output!

How to solve this, so i can still update a UI and keep the 100% transfer speed, not loosing the 60%?

Comment: Well, with 40MB/s and updating the UI every 4096 bytes, you are updating the UI about 10'000 times per second - no one is gone read the UI this fast. Try updating the UI less frequently (maybe every 400'000 bytes)

Comment: Well increasing the buffer size did it, the question is, is there any side effects? It is now considerably faster tho. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good candidate for using [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multi-threading. Update the UI in another thread. That thread must check your copying process (you will need a variable for this an you'll update it in your while loop). In the UI thread you will check every few seconds that variable and update the JFrame.